# I have a document with a unique alphabet, how can I translate it?

Tags: python, c++, document, translate

I have a document filled with weird characters, but I have the counterpart of the letters in another document.

Eg.

```
⟷ = a
⇳ = b
⤚ = c
```

etc...

I think that I can do this by using a dictionary, and a simple swap algorythm, but I'm still a newbie in programming. Do you think that's a good idea?
How can I translate the whole text (preferably using Python or C++), without having to use MS Word's built in "swap" tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes dictionary is an option. You could also look at [string.maketrans()](https://kite.com/python/docs/string.maketrans) method to do that.

```
from string import maketrans

intab = "aeiou"
outtab = "12345"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)

str = "this is string example....wow!!!";
print(str.translate(trantab))
```

will give output

```
th3s 3s str3ng 2x1mpl2....w4w!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you `translate` method in python from `string` module:

```
from string import maketrans

in_letters = "abc"               # and so on, you can add more letters
out_letters = ''.join(['⟷', '⇳', '⤚'])
t = maketrans(in_letters, out_letters)

with open('file.txt') as f:      # specify necessary filename
    text = f.read()
    translation = str.translate(t)
    print(translation)
```

Comment: why not just "⟷⇳⤚"?

Comment: @Caleth it seems to me that using list it looks clearer.